# How to copy single chars from an array of strings to another string in "C"

Tags: c, c-strings

**Here is my code, The problem is that all the strings of allwords[i] change to the same string in the last of the code**

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void print(int size, char *string)
{
    char* word;
    char** allwords;
    word = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    allwords = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int c = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if((*(string + i) == *(string))) /* if the start of the string is the same string of the original string */
        {
            for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
            {
                c++;
                int k;
                for (k = 0; k <= j - i; k++)
                    word[k] = string[k];
                for(int s = k; s < strlen(word); s++) /* prevents unknown symbols */
                    word[s] = '\0';
                allwords = realloc(allwords,(c+1)*sizeof(char*));
                allwords[c] = malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
                allwords[c] = word;

                for(int f = 0; f <= c; f ++) /* Deletes all the similar strings, and keeps only one */
                    for(int t = f + 1; t < c; t++)
                        if(allwords[f] == allwords[t])
                            allwords[t] = '\0';

                printf("%s\n",allwords[c]); /* prints the current string */
                printf("%s\n",allwords[0]); /* To check if allwords[0] has changed or not during the code */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Input: (3 , "abc")**
**Output: a a ab ab abc abc**

allwords[0] , allwords[1] , allwords[2] , all of them have "abc", but what I want is:

allwords[0] = "a" , allwords[1] = "ab" , allwords[2] = "abc"

I think that the problem is from malloc of allwords, but I don't know what I have to do to fix it, any suggestions ?.

Comment: Hint: Don't you see anything wrong with `allwords = malloc(size*sizeof(char))`?

Comment: By the way, for any array *or pointer* `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`.

Comment: Lastly, don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: To be honest, yes I see, I tried playing with that, but I didn't know what to put exactly, and if I have to use "realloc" each time I want to put a new string in word. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I rather mean the `sizeof(char)`, which is specified (by the C specification) to *always* be equal to `1`. Isn't `allwords` supposed to be an array of strings (i.e. an array of *pointers* to `char`)?

Comment: Are you trying to simply print all the prefixes?

Comment: should I put allwords = realloc(allwords , (c+1)*sizeof(word));

Comment: Exactly @SomethingSomething

Comment: @YamenMassalha `for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) { for (j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++) { printf("%c", string[j]); } printf("\n"); }`. First year in Madaey Hamachshev?

Comment: Haha exactly :D , first year @SomethingSomething
But your answer will print all of them more than 1 time, I want to prevent that.

Comment: :D My code will print each prefix only once. The first loop will tell each time where to stop. The internal loop will print the chars of the prefix each time

Comment: @SomethingSomething it worked, but I have another problem now, if I got a string "abbcad", the "ad" have to be printed too, becuase it start's with "a".

Comment: That's another problem for a possible other question. I suggest that you first [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) though.

Comment: Can you redefine what the function should print exactly?

Comment: I will edit the post and explain better, give me some minutes

Comment: @SomethingSomething , I've edited the question, now it explains my problem in the code.
The output have to be:
All the strings inside the original string that start's with the first letter as the original string.
Example : Input ( 4 , " abad")
Output : a , ab , aba , abad , ad

Comment: Removed the C++ tag. A good answer in C++ would be very different.

Comment: `for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) { if (string[i] == string[0]) { printf("%s\n", string + i); } }`

Comment: This will print all the suffixes that start with the first letter of the string

Comment: Replace `allwords[c] = word;` by `strcpy(allwords[c], word)`. Otherwise, you are copying pointers, and `word` changes along your flow

Comment: @SomethingSomething That's it !!, thank you a lot man :D

Comment: Hi, I can see you probably found solution, if nobody else will do, please put the answer to question as well. For future findings, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the answer from a friend**

Replacing allwords[c] = word;

by:

strcpy(allwords[c] , word);

Reason: " Otherwise, you are copying pointers, and word changes along your flow – "